# Where does hose out bottom of carburetor on Yamaha yw50ap go?

Tags: carburetor

Where does hose out bottom of carburetor on a Yamaha yw50ap go?

Comment: Is the hose currently attached to anything? Either way, a picture would probably be helpful here. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it looks down on the floor. Overflow pipe. Some have cut in angle, looks like syringe needle, some have a little bracket to screw it somewhere to engine aiming down. Basically the idea is not to spill over the engine.